# How can I solve this specific circular dependency?

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

In a snake game, I have two classes defined in seperate files: `Snake` and `Map` (a game map, not the usual container).

This is a simplified `Map` implementation:

```
#include "Snake.hpp"

using Coordinates = std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>;

class Map
{
   public:
    Map(Coordinates dimensions);
    void generateFruit(const Snake &);

   private:
    friend class Snake;
    const Coordinates m_dimensions;
    std::unordered_set<Coordinates, boost::hash<Coordinates>> m_fruit_positions;
};
```

`generateFruit` generates a fruit at a random position in the map, and it can't place a fruit where the snake exists, which means it needs to know where the snake is, hence the argument `Snake`.

And this is a simplified `Snake` implementation:

```
#include "Map.hpp"

class Snake
{
   public:
    enum class Orientation
    {
        Up,
        Down,
        Left,
        Right
    };
    Snake(const Map &);
    bool isAlive(const Map &) const;
    void move(Map &);
    void turn(Orientation);

   private:
    std::deque<Coordinates> s_snake;
    Orientation s_orientation;
};
```

Most methods in `Snake` require a `Map` for bounds checking.

What's the best way to resolve this dependency?

**EDIT**:
Forward declaring any class causes incomplete type errors.

Comment: `Map` only needs a reference to Snake, so it doesn't need a full include. Remove the `#include "Snake.hpp"` and forward declare. That said, map's in the same position. Just pick one.

Comment: That edit about "incomplete type errors" cries out for further explanation, and perhaps a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Make sure that in the cpp files you're actually including the headers you need. But the headers themselves can just forward declare.

Comment: @Beta forward declaring `class Snake` in `Map.hpp` or `class Map` in `Snake.hpp` is fine, but the compiler doesn't allow accessing members of the forward declared class, which I need to do in `generateFruit` and all the methods that require a `Map` in the `Snake` implementation.

Comment: Extra recommendations: **1** Always include matching header file first from the source file. **2** Minimize `#include` in the header file when appropriate to reduce compile-time dependencies.

Comment: @Kevin Including `Snake.hpp` in `Map.cpp` instead of in `Map.hpp`, as you suggested, along with a `class Snake` forward declaration in `Map.hpp` seemed to fix the issue. Thank you.